# How is transitive closure of a relation related to the cardinality of the set?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, relations

This is my question, and I don't know how to approach it.

$R$ is a binary relation on set $S$. $R_0$, $R_1$, $R_2$…. are defined as below:

$R_0 := I = \{(x,x) : x ∈ S\}$

$R_{n+1} := R_n ∪ (R;R_n)$ for $n >= 0$

There exists $i ∈ N$ such that $R_i = R_{i+1}$

If |S| = u, show that $R_{u^2} = R_{u^2 + 1}$ and explain the reason.

Comment: I’m not sure what the notation $(R;R_n)$ means, but the definition implies that if $R_i=R_{i+1}$, then $R_i=R_j$ whenever $j\ge i$, and that whenever $j\ge i$, $R_i\subseteq R_j$. This is enough. Hint: Let $s_1,s_2,\dots$ be a listing of $S$, and let $M_n$ be the $u\times u$ matrix whose $(i,j)$-th entry is $1$ if and only if $s_i R s_j$ and $0$ otherwise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HINT: $\langle a,b\rangle\in R_n$ if and only if there are $a_0=a,a_1,\ldots,a_n=b\in S$ such that $\langle a_k,a_{k+1}\rangle\in R$ for $k=0,\ldots,n-1$. If $n>u^2$, the pigeonhole principle says that there are distinct $k,\ell$ such that $\langle a_k,a_{k+1}\rangle=\langle a_\ell,a_{\ell+1}\rangle$.